# Is it safe to use Python's secrets module in a fresh docker container?

Tags: python, docker

If I create a new Docker container based on a recent Debian image, and if use this container to generate a cryptographic key using Python's `secrets` module, then is that key safe to use?

My understanding is that the `secrets` module is based on `random.SystemRandom`, which in turn relies on `os.urandom`. Its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) states:

> On Linux, if the `getrandom()` syscall is available, it is used in
> blocking mode: block until the system urandom entropy pool is
> initialized (128 bits of entropy are collected by the kernel). See the
> PEP 524 for the rationale. On Linux, the `getrandom()` function can be
> used to get random bytes in non-blocking mode (using the `GRND_NONBLOCK`
> flag) or to poll until the system `urandom` entropy pool is initialized.

I have no idea how to check whether or not the `getrandom()` syscall is available. And even if it is, can I trust the entropy pool on a Docker container, since it has less sources of entropy than a regular machine?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that my host OS is MacOS 12.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to mention here is that Docker containers (from the host's perspective) are just ordinary processes, they use the same kernal as any other program running on the host.

There are some layers of isolation in typical container setups and one of these will block some syscalls from inside containers, if you're running in Docker.

There's a list of the blocked syscalls [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) but I don't see any mention of getrandom, so I'd expect it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @rory-mccune, that's good news. I forgot to mention that my host OS is MacOS, I'm not sure whether this makes a difference?

Comment: So if you're using MacOS, what's happening under the covers (assuming you're using Docker Desktop) is that there's a Linux VM present that Docker manages for you. The syscall situation should be the same as with Docker straight onto Linux, as the containers are being run on that VM.